# jquery submit on change with a twist

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a single select_field that gets submitted via jquery whenever the select field is changed.I use something like this:

```
$('#scope').change(function() {
  this.form.submit();
});
```

Where scope is the ID of the select_field. This works as expected.

We want to change the view slightly where the select field is hidden until the user clicks a link => then it pops up and you can select as before.

**The problem:**
When the user clicks the link to show the select field. It also instantly triggers the change event somehow (even though the value of the select field has not changed).

Any easy way around this that I am overlooking?

Thanks for your time,
Erwin

Comment: Can you post the code that display/pops up the select field?

Comment: are you using any other tech? asp.net for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to register to the `change` event *after* you make the select-field visible

e.g.:

```
$(the_link_selector).click(function() {
    $('#scope')
       .show()
       .change(function () { this.form.submit(); });
});
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for: nice and simple. I was almost ready to start storing the value and seeing if that was changed, but I knew it had to be easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#scope").hide();
    $("#link").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#scope").show();
  });
    $("#scope").change(function() {
        $("#testform").submit();
    });
});
```

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/pramendra/yJkHa/1/)